# Respond_to block is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I can't get **respond_to** to work with **format.js**.

```
class UserSessionsController < UserApplicationController
  def create
    if @counterparty
      session[:counterparty_id] = @counterparty.id
      @counterparty.update(signed_in: true)
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email or password'
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.json { render json: @counterparty }
    end
  end
end
```

**views/user_sessions/create.js.erb**

```
alert("Please, notice me!")
```

**server logs**

```
Started POST "/user_login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-19 12:01:43 +0200
Processing by UserSessionsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "email"=>"ror@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Sing in"}
  Counterparty Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `counterparties`.* FROM `counterparties`  WHERE `counterparties`.`email` = 'ror@example.com' AND `counterparties`.`password` = 'faa90d7e56eb908c' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered user_sessions/create.js.erb within layouts/user_application (0.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_flash.slim (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 634ms (Views: 631.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

What's up with this?

Now, the most interesting part about it!

If I go like this my alert shows up, but that option doesn't suit me.

```
class UserSessionsController < UserApplicationController
 respond_to :js, only: :create

  def create
    if @counterparty
      session[:counterparty_id] = @counterparty.id
      @counterparty.update(signed_in: true)
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email or password'
    end

    respond_with(@counterparty, layout: false)
  end
end
```

**application.html.slim**

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title ActiveAccounting
    = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
    = csrf_meta_tags
    link href="favicon.ico" rel=("shortcut icon") type="image/x-icon" /
  body
    = render 'shared/flash'
    = yield
```

What do I do?

Comment: show your application.html.erb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your js template gets rendered inside application layout. You can prevent that by:

```
 format.js { render layout: false }
```

Or via a more global solution:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  layout proc{|c| c.request.xhr? ? false : "application" }
end
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you!